# Getting HTTP 408 Request Timeout when submitting a POST request from Jenkins but the same is working fine using Postman

Tags: post, jenkins, https, jenkins-plugins, newrelic

I'm calling an api (new relic insights api) and therefore using a HTTPs POST request (alongwith the required header) to call the api and run a NRQL query. Now, this POST request is working fine with Postman (or any other online tool for submitting https post request and I am getting the expected response as well, but when I try doing the same using HTTP Request Plugin in jenkins I am getting exceptions and errors as follows:-

> class org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException(Connect to
>   insights-api.newrelic.com:443
>   [insights-api.newrelic.com/50.31.164.169,
>   insights-api.newrelic.com/50.31.164.210,
>   insights-api.newrelic.com/50.31.164.207,
>   insights-api.newrelic.com/50.31.164.208,
>   insights-api.newrelic.com/50.31.164.209] failed: Connection timed out:
>   connect) as 408 Request Timeout

The POST request is as follows:-

`https://insights-api.newrelic.com/v1/accounts/******/query?nrql=SELECT%20count%28aonOperationNm%29%2C%20sum%28duration%29%2C%20average%28duration%29%2C%20min%28duration%29%2C%20max%28duration%29%2C%20percentile%28duration%2C%2090%29%2C%20percentile%28duration%2C%2095%29%2C%20percentile%28duration%2C%2099%29%20FROM%20Transaction%20WHERE%20appName%3D%20%27******%27%20FACET%20**************%20SINCE%20%272017-07-06%2007%3A33%3A00%20CDT%27%20UNTIL%20%272017-07-06%2008%3A07%3A00%20CDT%27%20limit%201000`

and the associated header that I need to pass is:-

```
*X-Query-Key* - ***************************
```

(data masked with ******)

I'm able to get response for this using postman but not with jenkins. Also, the machine I'm trying connects to the internet via a corporate proxy which has been already configured in jenkins (Manage plugins - advanced), still getting http 408 error. What could I be missing?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

What happens when you issue a `GET` instead of a `POST`?

This Insights API example provided [here](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/insights/insights-api/get-data/query-insights-event-data-api) via the New Relic docs uses a `GET`:

```
curl -H "Accept: application/json" -H "X-Query-Key: YOUR_QUERY_KEY" "https://insights-api.newrelic.com/v1/accounts/YOUR_ACCOUNT_ID/query?nrql=SELECT+count%28appName%29+FROM+PageView+SINCE+%272014-08-04+00%3A00%3A00%2B0500%27"
```

Comment: Both GET and POST work with Postman but neither works with Jenkins. I think its more of a jenkins/proxy issue than the request. For some reason the job isn't able to reach new relic.